# How to put "/" in search pattern in sed

Tags: bash, sed

`sed -i -e "/"project1/baz"/  s/foo/bar/" test.txt`

For example, i need to change word "foo" to word "bar" only if line contains "project1/baz", but as
"project1/baz" contains "/" it throws an error:
**sed: can't find label for jump to `az/'**
what if instead of "project1/baz" sed input contained variable?

Comment: Or just use a sigil other than `/`. If you use `s@foo@bar@`, then `foo` and `bar` can contain slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` to prevent it from terminating the address.

```
sed -i -e '/project\/baz/s/foo/bar' test.txt
```

---

Consider using the standard `ed` command instead of the non-standard `-i` option to `sed`.

```
ed test.txt <<EOF
/project\/baz/s/foo/bar
wq
EOF
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' '/project\/baz/s/foo/bar/' 'wq' | ed test.txt
```